# How can I disable tilt animation on GridView/ListView in Win10 Universal app?

Tags: xaml, uwp, windows-10, win-universal-app, winrt-xaml

It used to be I could cancel the tilt effect on GridView/ListView by editing the item container style and removing the storyboard animations.

However, when I edit the templates now on Win10 Universal apps, I am not seeing any of the storyboards. Where can I cancel the animation at?

Here's the style that's generated for me (and when used, does not disable animation):

```
<Style x:Key="ListViewItemStyle1" TargetType="ListViewItem">
  <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
  <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}"/>
  <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local"/>
  <Setter Property="IsHoldingEnabled" Value="True"/>
  <Setter Property="Padding" Value="12,0,12,0"/>
  <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
  <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
  <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemMinWidth}"/>
  <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemMinHeight}"/>
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <ListViewItemPresenter CheckBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumHighBrush}" ContentMargin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" CheckMode="Inline" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" CheckBoxBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumHighBrush}" DragForeground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragForegroundThemeBrush}" DragOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragThemeOpacity}" DragBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragBackgroundThemeBrush}" DisabledOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDisabledThemeOpacity}" FocusBorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundAltHighBrush}" FocusSecondaryBorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" PointerOverForeground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}" PressedBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListMediumBrush}" PlaceholderBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}" PointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListLowBrush}" ReorderHintOffset="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}" SelectedPressedBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentHighBrush}" SelectionCheckMarkVisualEnabled="True" SelectedForeground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}" SelectedPointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentMediumBrush}" SelectedBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentLowBrush}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 4):

One way is to block the interaction from the `ListViewItem` by inserting another `Control`.

For example, wrap the content inside the `ItemTemplate` with a `Button` with the following *almost empty* style.

```
<Style x:Key="EmptyButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<DataTemplate x:Name="ListViewItemTemplate">
    <Button Style="{StaticResource EmptyButtonStyle}">
        <!-- Put your original stuff here -->
    </Button>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply, you can just comment the `ListViewItemPresenter` in `ListViewContainerStyle` or replace it with `ContentPresenter`. But this will also remove some other effects like `PointOver`.

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE:**

When you look at the style of  ListBoxItem you will see the full VSM that you can be edited by yourself.

So,replace `ListViewItemPresenter` in `ListViewContainerStyle`with this below will remove the tilt animation but keep all of the other effect:

```
                <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Grid.Resources>
                        <Style x:Key="BaseContentPresenterStyle" TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI"/>
                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
                            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
                            <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
                            <Setter Property="LineStackingStrategy" Value="MaxHeight"/>
                            <Setter Property="TextLineBounds" Value="Full"/>
                            <Setter Property="OpticalMarginAlignment" Value="TrimSideBearings"/>
                        </Style>
                        <Style x:Key="BodyContentPresenterStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseContentPresenterStyle}" TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
                            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
                        </Style>
                    </Grid.Resources>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseLowBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="PressedBackground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListLowBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="PressedBackground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListMediumBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="PressedBackground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentLowBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="PressedBackground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentLowBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="SelectedPointerOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="PressedBackground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentMediumBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="SelectedPressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="PressedBackground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentHighBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="PressedBackground" Fill="Transparent" Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget="True"/>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Style="{StaticResource BodyContentPresenterStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Grid>
```

Comment: I would, but I'm not the OP

Comment: Be extra careful with this approach though. `ListViewItemPresenter` is designed to give the `ListView` a performance boost. Replacing it might not be a good idea.

Comment: So far there isn't any noticeable issue after using this method.

Comment: That's only because you are not loading large and complex data templates and/or not testing on low end devices. This is **not** the recommended approach.

Answer (score 1):

All examples here before are good but they lose other visual effects from component. Here is full working code, tested because I use them. Works on Windows 10 universal, on other windows versions maybe not.

THIS ONE IS FOR GRID VIEW...

```
   <!-- Style for Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.GridViewItem --- NO TILT EFFECT-->
    <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local"/>
        <Setter Property="IsHoldingEnabled" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,4,4"/>
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource GridViewItemMinWidth}"/>
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{ThemeResource GridViewItemMinHeight}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="GridViewItem">
                    <Grid x:Name="ContentBorder"
            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <!--<PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" />-->
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BorderRectangle"
                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                               Duration="0"
                               To="1"/>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListLowBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualBlack" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <!--<PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" />-->
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BorderRectangle"
                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                               Duration="0"
                               To="1"/>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListMediumBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualBlack" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <!--<PointerDownThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentPresenter" />-->
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MultiSelectCheck"
                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                               Duration="0"
                               To="1"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BorderRectangle"
                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                               Duration="0"
                               To="1"/>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualBlack" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MultiSelectSquare" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <!--<PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" />-->
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOverSelected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MultiSelectCheck"
                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                               Duration="0"
                               To="1"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BorderRectangle"
                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                               Duration="0"
                               To="1"/>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentMediumBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualBlack" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MultiSelectSquare" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <!--<PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" />-->
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PressedSelected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MultiSelectCheck"
                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                               Duration="0"
                               To="1"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BorderRectangle"
                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                               Duration="0"
                               To="1"/>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentHighBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualBlack" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MultiSelectSquare" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <!--<PointerDownThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentPresenter" />-->
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DisabledStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Enabled"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentBorder"
                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                               Duration="0"
                               To="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDisabledThemeOpacity}"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualWhite"
                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                               Duration="0"
                               To="1"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualBlack"
                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                               Duration="0"
                               To="1"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="MultiSelectStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="MultiSelectDisabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MultiSelectSquare" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible" />
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.333" Value="Collapsed" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="MultiSelectSquare"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MultiSelectEnabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MultiSelectSquare" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <FadeInThemeAnimation TargetName="MultiSelectSquare"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DataVirtualizationStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="DataAvailable"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="DataPlaceholder">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderRect" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ReorderHintStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="NoReorderHint"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="BottomReorderHint">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DragOverThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentBorder" ToOffset="{ThemeResource GridViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}" Direction="Bottom" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="TopReorderHint">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DragOverThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentBorder" ToOffset="{ThemeResource GridViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}" Direction="Top" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="RightReorderHint">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DragOverThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentBorder" ToOffset="{ThemeResource GridViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}" Direction="Right" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="LeftReorderHint">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DragOverThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentBorder" ToOffset="{ThemeResource GridViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}" Direction="Left" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition To="NoReorderHint" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.2"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DragStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="NotDragging" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="Dragging">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentBorder"
                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                               Duration="0"
                               To="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragThemeOpacity}" />
                                        <DragItemThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentBorder" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="DraggingTarget">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DropTargetItemThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentBorder" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MultipleDraggingPrimary">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <!-- These two Opacity animations are required - the FadeInThemeAnimations
                                       on the same elements animate an internal Opacity. -->
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MultiArrangeOverlayBackground"
                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                               Duration="0"
                               To="1" />
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MultiArrangeOverlayText"
                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                               Duration="0"
                               To="1" />
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentBorder"
                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                               Duration="0"
                               To="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragThemeOpacity}" />
                                        <FadeInThemeAnimation TargetName="MultiArrangeOverlayBackground" />
                                        <FadeInThemeAnimation TargetName="MultiArrangeOverlayText" />
                                        <DragItemThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentBorder" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MultipleDraggingSecondary">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentBorder" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="DraggedPlaceholder">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentBorder" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition To="NotDragging" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.2"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                        ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                        HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                        Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" />
                        <!-- The 'Xg' text simulates the amount of space one line of text will occupy.
                        In the DataPlaceholder state, the Content is not loaded yet so we
                        approximate the size of the item using placeholder text. -->
                        <TextBlock x:Name="PlaceholderTextBlock"
                  Visibility="Collapsed"
                  Text="Xg"
                  Foreground="{x:Null}"
                  Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                  IsHitTestVisible="False"
                  AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"/>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="PlaceholderRect"
                  Visibility="Collapsed"
                  Fill="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="MultiArrangeOverlayBackground"
                  IsHitTestVisible="False"
                  Opacity="0"
                  Fill="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                  Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="BorderRectangle"
                  IsHitTestVisible="False"
                  Stroke="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentLowBrush}"
                  StrokeThickness="2"
                  Opacity="0"/>
                        <Border x:Name="MultiSelectSquare"
              Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundChromeMediumBrush}"
              Width="20"
              Height="20"
              Margin="0,2,2,0"
              VerticalAlignment="Top"
              HorizontalAlignment="Right"
              Visibility="Collapsed" >
                            <FontIcon x:Name="MultiSelectCheck"
                  FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}"
                  Glyph="&#xE73E;"
                  FontSize="16"
                  Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumHighBrush}"
                  Opacity="0"/>
                        </Border>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualWhite"
                  IsHitTestVisible="False"
                  Stroke="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundAltHighBrush}"
                  StrokeEndLineCap="Square"
                  StrokeDashArray="1.0, 1.0"
                  StrokeDashOffset="1.5"
                  StrokeThickness="2"
                  Opacity="0"/>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualBlack"
                  IsHitTestVisible="False"
                  Stroke="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}"
                  StrokeEndLineCap="Square"
                  StrokeDashArray="1.0, 1.0"
                  StrokeDashOffset="0.5"
                  StrokeThickness="2"
                  Opacity="0"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="MultiArrangeOverlayText"
                  Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.DragItemsCount}"
                  Foreground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragForegroundThemeBrush}"
                  FontFamily="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"
                  FontSize="26.667"
                  IsHitTestVisible="False"
                  Opacity="0"
                  TextWrapping="Wrap"
                  TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"
                  Margin="18,9,0,0"
                  AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                  Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

THIS ONE IS FOR LIST VIEW...

```
<!-- Style for Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ListViewItem --- NO TILT EFFECT-->
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local"/>
        <Setter Property="IsHoldingEnabled" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="12,0,12,0"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemMinWidth}"/>
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemMinHeight}"/>
        <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Grid x:Name="ContentBorder"
          Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
          BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
          BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <!--<PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" />-->
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BorderBackground"
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                             Duration="0"
                             To="1"/>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListLowBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <!--<PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" />-->
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BorderBackground"
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                             Duration="0"
                             To="1"/>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListMediumBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <!--<PointerDownThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentPresenter" />-->
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MultiSelectCheck"
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                             Duration="0:0:0"
                             To="1"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BorderBackground"
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                             Duration="0"
                             To="1"/>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentLowBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <!--<PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" />-->
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOverSelected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MultiSelectCheck"
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                             Duration="0:0:0"
                             To="1"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BorderBackground"
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                             Duration="0"
                             To="1"/>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentMediumBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <!--<PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" />-->
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PressedSelected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MultiSelectCheck"
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                             Duration="0:0:0"
                             To="1"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BorderBackground"
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                             Duration="0"
                             To="1"/>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentHighBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <!--<PointerDownThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentPresenter" />-->
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DisabledStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Enabled"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentBorder"
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                             Duration="0"
                             To="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDisabledThemeOpacity}"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="MultiSelectStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="MultiSelectDisabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MultiSelectCheckBoxTransform"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="X">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="0"/>
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.333" Value="-32" KeySpline="0.1,0.9,0.2,1"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MultiSelectClipTransform"
                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="X">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="0"/>
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.333" Value="32" KeySpline="0.1,0.9,0.2,1"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenterTranslateTransform"
                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="X">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="32"/>
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.333" Value="0" KeySpline="0.1,0.9,0.2,1"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MultiSelectSquare" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible" />
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.333" Value="Collapsed" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MultiSelectEnabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MultiSelectCheckBoxTransform"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="X">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="-32"/>
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.333" Value="0" KeySpline="0.1,0.9,0.2,1"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MultiSelectClipTransform"
                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="X">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="32"/>
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.333" Value="0" KeySpline="0.1,0.9,0.2,1"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenterTranslateTransform"
                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="X">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="-32"/>
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.333" Value="0" KeySpline="0.1,0.9,0.2,1"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MultiSelectSquare" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MultiSelectCheck" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenterGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="32,0,0,0" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DataVirtualizationStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="DataAvailable"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="DataPlaceholder">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderRect" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ReorderHintStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="NoReorderHint"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="BottomReorderHint">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DragOverThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentBorder" ToOffset="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}" Direction="Bottom" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="TopReorderHint">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DragOverThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentBorder" ToOffset="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}" Direction="Top" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="RightReorderHint">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DragOverThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentBorder" ToOffset="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}" Direction="Right" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="LeftReorderHint">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DragOverThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentBorder" ToOffset="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}" Direction="Left" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition To="NoReorderHint" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.2"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DragStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="NotDragging" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="Dragging">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentBorder"
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                             Duration="0"
                             To="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragThemeOpacity}" />
                                        <DragItemThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentBorder" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="DraggingTarget">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DropTargetItemThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentBorder" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MultipleDraggingPrimary">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <!-- These two Opacity animations are required - the FadeInThemeAnimations
                                     on the same elements animate an internal Opacity. -->
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MultiArrangeOverlayBackground"
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                             Duration="0"
                             To="1" />
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MultiArrangeOverlayText"
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                             Duration="0"
                             To="1" />
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentBorder"
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                             Duration="0"
                             To="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragThemeOpacity}" />
                                        <FadeInThemeAnimation TargetName="MultiArrangeOverlayBackground" />
                                        <FadeInThemeAnimation TargetName="MultiArrangeOverlayText" />
                                        <DragItemThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentBorder" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MultipleDraggingSecondary">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentBorder" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="DraggedPlaceholder">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentBorder" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition To="NotDragging" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.2"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="BorderBackground"
                IsHitTestVisible="False"
                Fill="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentLowBrush}"
                Opacity="0"
                Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget="True"/>
                        <Grid x:Name="ContentPresenterGrid"
          Background="Transparent"
          Margin="0,0,0,0">
                            <Grid.RenderTransform>
                                <TranslateTransform x:Name="ContentPresenterTranslateTransform"/>
                            </Grid.RenderTransform>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                        ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                        Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                        HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                        Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <!-- The 'Xg' text simulates the amount of space one line of text will occupy.
                      In the DataPlaceholder state, the Content is not loaded yet so we
                      approximate the size of the item using placeholder text. -->
                        <TextBlock x:Name="PlaceholderTextBlock"
                Opacity="0"
                Text="Xg"
                Foreground="{x:Null}"
                Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                IsHitTestVisible="False"
                AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"/>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="PlaceholderRect"
                Visibility="Collapsed"
                Fill="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="MultiArrangeOverlayBackground"
                IsHitTestVisible="False"
                Opacity="0"
                Fill="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
                        <Border x:Name="MultiSelectSquare"
            BorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumHighBrush}"
            BorderThickness="2"
            Width="20"
            Height="20"
            Margin="12,0,0,0"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Visibility="Collapsed" >
                            <Border.Clip>
                                <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,20,20">
                                    <RectangleGeometry.Transform>
                                        <TranslateTransform x:Name="MultiSelectClipTransform"/>
                                    </RectangleGeometry.Transform>
                                </RectangleGeometry>
                            </Border.Clip>
                            <Border.RenderTransform>
                                <TranslateTransform x:Name="MultiSelectCheckBoxTransform"/>
                            </Border.RenderTransform>
                            <FontIcon x:Name="MultiSelectCheck"
                FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}"
                Glyph="&#xE73E;"
                FontSize="16"
                Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumHighBrush}"
                Visibility="Collapsed"
                Opacity="0"/>
                        </Border>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="MultiArrangeOverlayText"
                Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.DragItemsCount}"
                Foreground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragForegroundThemeBrush}"
                FontFamily="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"
                FontSize="26.667"
                IsHitTestVisible="False"
                Opacity="0"
                TextWrapping="Wrap"
                TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"
                Margin="18,9,0,0"
                AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it. Just add this in your **App.xaml**

```
<Application
    ...>
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            ...
            <Style TargetType="ListView">
                <Setter Property="ItemContainerTransitions">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <TransitionCollection/>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Comment: Does nothing for me.