# SelectedPointerOver and SelectedPressed do not work for custom ListViewItem style in Windows 10 Universal App

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app, windows-10, app.xaml

I'm using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33279136/how-can-i-disable-tilt-animation-on-gridview-listview-in-win10-universal-app) for disabling tilt animation effect on ListView item container. This code works great, but visual states **SelectedPointerOver** and **SelectedPressed** are not triggered: when I mouse over/press the selected item it does not change the background color.

Here is the Style code from App.xaml:

```
<Style x:Key="NavigationListViewStyle" TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                        <Grid x:Name="RootGrid">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="PressedBackground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF323A45" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="PressedBackground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF3C4550" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="PressedBackground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF46293B" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="SelectedPointerOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="PressedBackground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF553549" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="SelectedPressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="PressedBackground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF603851" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="PressedBackground" Fill="Transparent" Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget="True"/>
                            <ContentPresenter />
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

And the control code:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="0" x:Name="NavigationListView" ItemsSource="{x:Bind NavigationList, Mode=OneTime}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                          ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ItemContainerStyle="{ThemeResource NavigationListViewStyle}" IsItemClickEnabled="False"
                          SelectionChanged="NavigationListView_SelectionChanged">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:MenuItem">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="15">
                                <FontIcon FontFamily="ms-appx:/Fonts/Icons.ttf#icons" Glyph="{x:Bind GlyphCode}" Foreground="{ThemeResource AccentColorBrush}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Title}" Margin="30,0,0,0" Foreground="White" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
```

I'm using Windows SDK 10.1.10586.15 with VS2015 Update 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In UWP visual states of ListViewItem is changed. You can open the project in Blend and edit ItemContainerStyle. Following styles will be generated

```
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
<Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
<Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
<Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}" />
<Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local"/>
<Setter Property="IsHoldingEnabled" Value="True"/>
<Setter Property="Padding" Value="12,0,12,0"/>
<Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
<Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
<Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemMinWidth}"/>
<Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemMinHeight}"/>
<Setter Property="Template">
  <Setter.Value>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
      <ListViewItemPresenter
          ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
          SelectionCheckMarkVisualEnabled="True"
          CheckBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumHighBrush}"
          CheckBoxBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumHighBrush}"
          DragBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragBackgroundThemeBrush}"
          DragForeground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragForegroundThemeBrush}"
          FocusBorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundAltHighBrush}"
          FocusSecondaryBorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}"
          PlaceholderBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}"
          PointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListLowBrush}"
          PointerOverForeground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}"
          SelectedBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentLowBrush}"
          SelectedForeground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}"
          SelectedPointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentMediumBrush}"
          PressedBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListMediumBrush}"
          SelectedPressedBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentHighBrush}"
          DisabledOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDisabledThemeOpacity}"
          DragOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragThemeOpacity}"
          ReorderHintOffset="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}"
          HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
          VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
          ContentMargin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
          CheckMode="Inline"/>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
</Style>
```

From above style edit **SelectedPressedBackground** **`SelectedPointerOverBackground`** of `ListViewItemPresenter`.

If you want visual states go through this [Default styles of ListViewItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299136.aspx)

Comment: Glad it worked. Please mark the answer as correct then :)